# Not displaying the products from the cart

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $name = isset($_GET['NameOfTheDVD']) ? ($_GET['NameOfTheDVD']): "";
      $DVDID = isset($_GET['DVDID']) ? ($_GET['DVDID']) : "";
      $Quantity =isset($_GET['Quantity']) ? ($_GET['Quantity']) : "";
    $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

    if($action=='removed'){
        echo "<div>" . $_GET['NameOfTheDVD'] . " was removed from cart.</div>";
    }

       if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $ids = " ";
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $DVDID){

        }

        // remove the last comma
        $ids = rtrim($ids, ',');

        require "connect.php";

        $query = "SELECT DVDID, NameOfTheDVD, Quantity FROM DVD WHERE DVDID IN ({$ids})";
        $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();

        $num = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($num>0){
            echo "<table border='0'>";//start table

                // our table heading
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='textAlignLeft'>Product Name</th>";
                    echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
                    echo "<th>Action</th>";
                echo "</tr>";

                //also compute for total price
                $totalQuantity = 0;

                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    extract($row);

                    $totalQuantity += $Quantity;

                    //creating new table row per record
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
                        echo "<td class='textAlignRight'>{$Quantity}</td>";
                        echo "<td class='textAlignCenter'>";
                            echo "<a href='RemoveFromCart.php?DVDID={$DVDID}&name={$name}' class='customButton'>";
                                echo "<img src='images/remove-from-cart.png' title='Remove from cart' />";
                            echo "</a>";
                        echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='textAlignCenter'>Total Price</th>";
                    echo "<th class='textAlignRight'>{$totalQuantity}</th>";
                    echo "<th></th>";
                echo "</tr>";

            echo "</table>";
            echo "<br /><div><a href='#' class='customButton'>Checkout</a></div>";
        }else{
            echo "<div>No products found in your cart. :(</div>";
        }

    }else{
        echo "<div>No products in cart yet.</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

This is where the products are meant to be displayed but it does not display. I dont know what the problem is. I dont know if there should be some kind if statement checking if the Session is empty if not display the results. There were 2 topics related to this on Stack overflow but I don't think they were solved.

This is my AddtoCart.php

```
<?php
   session_start();

   // get the product id
   $DVDID = isset($_GET['DVDID']) ? $_GET['DVDID'] : "";
   $name = isset($_GET['NameOfTheDVD']) ? $_GET['NameOfTheDVD'] : "";

   /* 
    * check if the 'cart' session array was created
    * if it is NOT, create the 'cart' session array
 . */
   if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
     $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    }

   // check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
   if(in_array($DVDID, $_SESSION['cart'])){
      // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
      header('Location: shop.php?action=exists&DVDID' . $DVDID . '&name=' . $name);
    }

     // else, add the item to the array
    else{
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $DVDID);

    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    header('Location: shop.php?action=add&DVDID' . $DVDID . '&name=' . $name);
    }

?>
```

Thanks for any help provided

Comment: Have you tried adding debugging output (extra `echo`s, `var_dump`s, etc) or anything? Are there any errors? Do your SQL statements work?  "it does not display" is not much to go on here...

Comment: Sidenote: `session_start();` needs to be inside all your files I only see it in your last body of code. *Possibly even the answer.* `(19:27:55)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just added that

Comment: Even in your DB connection file and any other possibly included file(s)?

Comment: @Cory I added this code var_dump($_SESSION['cart']); it gave me an error "Undefined Index:cart" and then next to that I got Null. ALl MYSQL statements work

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yh I just added that and it still does not seem to display the result

Comment: Ok. Well, instead of doing `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();` can you try `$_SESSION['cart'] = $_GET['NameOfTheDVD'];` or something similar?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yh I added that and now when I tried `var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);` its giving me NULL. Does that mean the session ['cart'] is empty?

Comment: Sounds like it. Multi-sessions stuff are not my strong point. Sessions can be very tricky. All I can suggest at this point, is that you do up a test script on a smaller scale. I'd like to help you further, but that's about the limit of my scope of knowledge.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me.

Comment: @Cory Have you got any suggestions for me?

Comment: Just one last suggestion, try doing `$_SESSION['cart']=$name;` since it's appearing in `$name = isset($_GET['NameOfTheDVD']) ? ($_GET['NameOfTheDVD']): "";`

Comment: WOW SOME PROGRSSS. I am getting this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in " @Fred-ii-

Comment: That is something new I have got

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $ids = " ";
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $DVDID){
      
        }` This is where I am getting the error

Comment: Error messages are progress, now keep that for now. Instead of doing this now `foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $DVDID){` try switching them around `foreach($DVDID as $_SESSION['cart']){` while keeping your `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();`

Comment: Nopee, no difference @Fred-ii-

Comment: And what if you changed `$name = isset($_GET['NameOfTheDVD']) ? ($_GET['NameOfTheDVD']): "";` to `$name = isset($_SESSION['NameOfTheDVD']) ? ($_SESSION['NameOfTheDVD']): "";` and/or `$DVDID = isset($_GET['DVDID']) ? ($_GET['DVDID']) : "";` to `$DVDID = isset($_SESSION['DVDID']) ? ($_SESSION['DVDID']) : "";`

Comment: well i did try this `if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $ids = "";
  $_SESSION['cart'] = $_GET[$DVDID];
     $_SESSION['cart'] = $_GET[$name];
     $_SESSION['cart'] = $_GET[$Quantity];
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $DVDID){
     $ids = $ids . $id . ",";`

Comment: and it did not seem to work @Fred-ii-

Comment: I can't test this because setting up a DB would just take too much time. Either you test this on a much smaller scale, or try and Google `multiple cart items sessions php` see if that will render helpful results.